# Windows 7 recreate my .exes

Tags: windows, file, restore

I have a few programs that check if a file exists. If it is an old version delete it and paste the new version. However, under Windows 7 Professional I can't delete the file.  Some System process is always restoring it (same with the dll files). As you can imagine a lot of programs are crashing because of that behavior. So WHAT SERVICE/PROCESS can lock/recreate/restore files? I have disabled System Recovery.

Comment: This sounds like a question for http://superuser.com

Comment: Vote to close as off-topic as it's already been asked on Super User. Migrating will only create a duplicate.

Comment: ChrisF: I think you should provide a link to the question there, so somebody who finds this page will be able to get an answer.

Comment: @Gabe (and any one else who's interested) the question on Super User is at http://superuser.com/questions/152027/windows-7-recreate-my-exe-dll-files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out the problem it was disabled Microsoft services - Program Compatibility and Application Expirience